# Help identify network cables & connectors in home network?

Tags: cables, connectors, internet, network

I moved into a new house that appears to have network cables run from a closet to all the bedrooms. (Bedrooms all have wall plates with RJ-45 ports.)

However, I need help understanding/identifying what's going on in the closet. I expected a bunch of separate cables, which I would then attach to a patch panel. Instead, as pictured, I find the cables partially attached to each other - all the blues wires seem to be grouped together in a "Dolphin" sleeve, & likewise the other colors.

- What is the purpose of this setup?
- Why are the colored wires grouped?
- What is the roundish red connector that ties a few (not all) of the green wires together?
- Why a bunch of loose wires?
- Should I undo the connectors & attach the cables to a patch panel?

Bottom line is I want a wired network & internet connection to all my bedrooms. What're my options?

[image: Network cables]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Home Ethernet "patch" panel - how to approach?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/234576/home-ethernet-patch-panel-how-to-approach).  I found this one duplicate, but if you search for "patch panel" there are several questions that deal with this exact situation.  Basically, this is Cat5 run as phone cable.  Just cut off all the spices and re-terminate as network cable and install a switch/router in the cabinet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using 2 pairs of wires (blue/blue white, orange, orange/white) to run two different sets of phone lines.  All of the same color are grouped so that you can install a phone in any of the jacks --in a standard installation in an RJ-45 jack, these are the center wires:
https://incentre.net/ethernet-cable-color-coding-diagram/

I'd guess that the two wires that are connected with the 'telephone' connectors lead to one actual phone line entering the house -- this setup allows you to have phone jacks anywhere.

Additionally:   You can remove the wall plates and verify that the RJ45 jacks are wired as per the T568-A standard (or even if all the other wires are pushed down at all)

Should you wish to reuse these cables as standard ethernet cables, you'll need to match the cabling standard on your patch panel.

Comment: **One** standard. TIA 568A, specifically. Whereas the vast majority of network jacks follow TIA 568B, for whatever reason, or no reason. Have to be aware of what you actually have. This could date back far enough to have been running PhoneNet on the orange pair (240KB data around the house - whoo-hoo!)

Comment: @Ecnerwal  This is an excellent point.  OP needs to check  the wall plates to verify.